# Why is "allowing" used instead of "allows" in "allowing teams to detect problems early"?

Tags: verbs, present-participles

I have read an article and noticed a sentence:

> Each check-in is then verified by an automated build, allowing teams to detect problems early.

Why do they use **allowing** instead of **allows**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it gerund or participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252511/is-it-gerund-or-participle)

Comment: Per answer on linked duplicate question, the ***-ing*** form here is because it's a ***participle*** introducing an adjectival clause that (modifies the "subject" noun ***an automated build***). It would be a normal inflected verb if that clause were changed to *directly* reference the subject: ***...which allows** [early detection]*.

Comment: Or you could say the participle clause ***adverbially*** modifies the verb ***verifies***. In theory that *could* affect the meaning in some subtle way, but in practice I don't see it makes any difference here. ***Or*** you could say it's a "sentence adverb" usage, with that final clause applying to the entire preceding text taken as a single semantic unit. It's all the same in terms of *meaning* though, just different views on the syntactic relationships.

Comment: Because it is a non-finite clause. It could be replaced with little semantic  difference by the non-defining relative clause "Each check-in is then verified by an automated build, _which allows teams to detect problems early_".

Comment: @BillJ: The question is: *Is it the "automated build" that does this?* It might be that it's *the act of performing the verification* that enables early detection.  I think the syntactic construction is "ambiguous" on that front, and although it might *seem* to be a semantically irrelevant distinction in this *exact* context, that might not be quite true. And I expect there would be other versions of "the same" construction where the different interpretations could be more strongly contrasted.

Comment: It's simply two ways of saying the same thing, one using a non-finite clause, and the other using a finite relative clause. No real difference in meaning. |Either way, the clause does not modify anything, but has a semantic 'anchor', in this case the entire preceding clause.

Comment: Yes, the participle is as ambiguous as a relative clause with a summarizing _which_.  In discourse such as _which_ can refer to the entire past discourse, or any particular part of it, at the discretion of the speaker, and by the inference of the addressee, which usually lead to minutely different descriptions of the same event, which nobody ever learns or cares about.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't just insert "allows" in place of "allowing". You'd need to say either "*which* allows", or "*that* allows".

However, "that allows" would define the "automated build" as being the thing that makes it possible for teams to detect problems, and that doesn't seem to be the case. It is the process of verification that does this.

"Which allows" would refer to the entire previous clause, the process of verification. "Allowing" does exactly the same. It really is just a style choice. If there was any difference at all, "which allows" makes it a little clearer that the *intended purpose* of the verification is the detection of problems, not just a useful by-product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer *why*, but there are two ways of expressing this sentence:

1. Each check-in is then verified by an automated build, **allowing** teams to detect problems early.
2. Each check-in is then verified by an automated build, **which allows** teams to detect problems early.

Comment: It's called a participle phrase or participle clause.  https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses#:~:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc.).